Nodemailer returns success message but doesn't send email
I'm trying to set up a contact form for my website that I'm building using React. I used nodemailer to send emails using this form. It works perfectly when I test it out locally, but when I hosted it on plesk it stopped working.
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});

app.post('/sendMail' , async (req, res) => {
    const { lastName, firstName, email, company, phoneNumber,  message } = req.body;
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            sendmail:true,
            newline:"unix",
            path:"/usr/sbin/sendmail",
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            secure : true,
            auth: {
                user: USER,
                pass: PWD
            },
            tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized : false,
            }
        });
    
        let mailOptions = {
            from: dest,
            to: src,
            subject: `New message from ${lastName} ${firstName}`,
            html: `<p>Hello,</p>
            <p>You got a new message from ${lastName} ${firstName}:</p>
            <p style="padding: 12px; border-left: 4px solid #d0d0d0; font-style: italic;">
                ${message}
            </p>
            
            <p>
             <b> Téle: </b> ${phoneNumber}  <br>
             <b> Company: </b> ${company}  <br>
            </p>
            <p>
              Best wishes,<br>
            </p>  
            `
        };

        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, messageResponse: 'Email sent!' });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, messageResponse: error.message });
    }
});

When I try send out the form, I get a 502 response.
On the other hand, when I use this to simply test out the code, I get a success response back but the email doesn't actually get sent.
app.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            sendmail:true,
            newline:"unix",
            path:"/usr/sbin/sendmail",
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            secure : false,
            auth: {
                user: USER,
                pass: PWD
            },
            tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized : false
            }
        });
    
        let mailOptions = {
            from: dest,
            to: src,
            subject: `New message from jkqsjqsjsjsj`,
            html: `<p>Hello,</p>
            <p>You got a new message from qsdfqsfsdfsdfd:</p>
            <p style="padding: 12px; border-left: 4px solid #d0d0d0; font-style: italic;">
                WSdwfsd
            </p>
            
            <p>
             <b> Téle: </b> qqqq  <br>
             <b> Company: </b> qsdfsfs<br>
            </p>
            <p>
              Best wishes,<br>
            </p>  
            `
        };

        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, messageResponse: info.message });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, messageResponse: error.message });
    }
});

What could be the issue?
